# Can someone please let me know which verse in the Quran the individual in this video is referring to?

Tags: quran, verses

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux8uD2R121I&t=858s

> I am specifically referring to the verse he says from 28:40 to 28:45.

Comment: I'd advise being wary of religious programs on geo and the views of ghamdi.

Comment: As the video seems to be in Urdu I'd usually close this question as unclear as the language of this site is English.

Comment: @UmH I appreciate your advice. I judge the views of Ghamidi/Geo based on their evidence - the same way I judge the points made by any other scholar/show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [28:40](https://youtu.be/Ux8uD2R121I?t=1720) he is quoting the following verse:

> #### قل لا أجد في ما أوحي إلي محرما على طاعم يطعمه إلا أن يكون ميتة أو دما مسفوحا أو لحم خنزير فإنه رجس أو فسقا أهل لغير الله به فمن اضطر غير باغ ولا عاد فإن ربك غفور رحيم
>
> Say, "I do not find within that which was revealed to me [anything] forbidden to one who would eat it unless it be a dead animal or blood spilled out or the flesh of swine - for indeed, it is impure - or it be [that slaughtered in] disobedience, dedicated to other than Allah. But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its limit], then indeed, your Lord is Forgiving and Merciful."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:145](http://quran.com/6/145)</sup>